# Poker starting pairs ranked by probability?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory

Where can I find the 1326 Texas Hold'em combinations of starting hands ranked **by a probability of winning** against a random pair? Some reliable overview by the probability would also cut it!

Comment: Googling your question title yields the answer on literally the first hit.

Comment: Unfortunately, that only shows first 10 best hands.

Comment: @NuclearWang No. Read the question before jumping at people's throat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable source from real games I've found is here - enjoy! https://www.tightpoker.com/poker_hands.html

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of tool out there that helps you achieve this.

1. Slansky hand group. This method groups all the hands into different categories based on probability. More info here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_hold_%27em_starting_hands

2. Use some online poker odds calculator, e.g. twodimes.net or edge.poker.